Poor INP when clicking on external link
On a webpage in a React application, there is some text which comes from API. I am further using linkify-html to convert the embedded links in text to anchor tags. Each anchor tag corresponds to an external link and opens it in a new tab/window. I am using web-vitals to analyze the performance of my page. As per RUM analysis, INP (Interaction to Next Paint) metric is poor due to this a tag's click interaction. I want to understand how is INP for an external link is calculated and what could be potential reasons for this issue?

Clicking on links are a little tricky in terms of INP as the "next paint" is often on the next page and not this page. Therefore they are often excluded when this is the case. The next page load is calculated by LCP and measuring it again with INP makes little sense.
Where they can be seen in INP, is if there is a "next paint" on this page. This can happen in a number of cases:

The link is a so-called "soft navigation" on an SPA so, as far as the browser is concerned, that is still "this page".
Where there is a JavaScript event handler on the link or on the page which results in a paint (e.g. a beforeunload handler that pops up a "You have unsaved data, do you realy wanna leave" alert).

There also was a bug for this for pages opened in next tabs that was fixed some time ago, but older versions of browsers may still experience this. See if you can filter your field data by browser type to identify if this is the case. Samsung Internet browsers for example are often a number of versions of Chromium behind and so can still show this bug.

Excuse my English, I'm French. I don't agree with what you're explaining Barry. I solved a problem of bad INP score which was caused by all the links that opened in a new tab. By removing the opening of links in new windows, my INP score decreased and improved my core web vitals performances.
I hadn't found where the problem came from for months. I analyzed the INP scores live by interacting on the pages, the values ​​were good; 50ms, 60ms... while the Google console indicated scores of 300ms for the INP. I was tearing my hair out.
So if this can help some webmasters, yes, the opening of links in a new tab or not has a major impact on the INP score. Contrary to everything the web says, Google first, saying that it doesn't look at that. Wrong! Or maybe I just taught them how their tool works lol
Peace from France

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
